# How do I eat a mango without getting sticky?

Tags: food

It's been suggested that the best place to eat a mango is in the bathtub.

**How can I eat mango without getting very sticky?**

Comment: Try with a spoon?

Comment: Who eats mangoes in a bathtub?

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion It's a joke because it's said you get so sticky from eating one that you need to take a bath immediately

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a special cutting technique, it can be easily done. Just use a knife and a fork. If you use gloves, you do it more elegantly. The trick is to cut it in a special way:

[image: Mango hedgehog]

- Cut it in half
- Cut a grid
- Put pressure on the shell. The shell of the mango is stiff to support a structure, that looks like a hedgehog.

It is [depicted on mango.org](http://www.mango.org/how-cut-mango) and explained.

Answer (score 0):

I do have a hack, for a ripe mango.

I really dont eat it, I prefer to crush it to the point where it is almost semi-liquid and then just bite the bottom edge of it and then suck the entire thing.

Comment: The pleasure if eating the mango will be lost using this hack. Maybe the OP is better off eating it in the bathtub.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I eat a lot of mangoes (being indian) and yes while cutting it into slices is a great way of doing it, I enjoy eating mangoes this way as well and regarding bathtubs... may be I wont try that :P

Comment: I personally like pieces of mango. If I wanted juice I'd buy juice... :)

Answer (score 0):

You could always eat dried mango?

The flavor is still there, and there is no stickyness. There are even methods of eating it that semi-rehydrate the mango in your mouth, and it has the nice experience.

[image]

[Tesco](http://www.tesco.com/groceries/product/details/?id=260733201) [Wallmart](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Great-Value-Sweetened-Dried-Mango-6-oz/17179143)

Comment: I don't think this answers the question being asked.

Comment: "How to eat mango without getting sticky?" This answers that...

Comment: That argument would be the same as "how do I swim without getting my hair wet?"... "don't swim". The OP is asking how to eat a mango implying it is fresh due to the messiness of it's nature. Dried mango ***is not*** ripe/fresh mango.

Comment: No, but it is mango...

Comment: @Phlume No, that's an improper comparison. The argument would be more akin to "how do I swim without getting my hair wet?" -> "Shave your head."

Comment: ... fair enough. the point is still made though, no?

Comment: @Phlume No, it is not because shaving your head is a valid answer to "how do I swim without getting my hair wet?" The only other possible answer would be "wear a swim cap", which would be using a product (which is apparently not allowed), or "waterproof your hair", which also be using a product.

Comment: @Origin fix a plastic bag to your head would be a valid answer. Shave your head is not (as its totally missing the point).

Comment: Thats quite hacky :D It is completely correct answer!